# Select element from list by index - Playwright

Tags: javascript, cucumber, playwright

After getting a list of elements by a common selector, how do I then select a single element from that list by it's index?

```
  When('click the first item in the list', async () => {
      const rows = await page.$$('.row-item');
      await page.click(rows[0]); <-- error message generated by this line
  });
```

The error message I get when trying the above is:

> // Argument of type 'ElementHandle<SVGElement | HTMLElement>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?
`rows[0].click()`

Answer (score 0):

It should work:

```js
 const [row] = await page.$$('.row-item');
 await row.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
  const rows = await page.$$('.row-item');
  await rows[0].click()
```